# MVVM Collections loading asynchrounously

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I have a view model with 5 collections.

All of them load asynchronously.

I need to load the main entity from a service and set the selected value of each collection based of the value in the entity. How do I wait until all the collections have been loaded before loading the entity and setting the selected values?

I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

When your `MainViewModel` (the one with the "main entity") completes loading set its `SelectedRecord` property. Setting this property should raise an event or broadcast a message that your other ViewModels can listen to.

When the other ViewModels receive the message from the main view model, set an `IsDirty` flag to true. The other ViewModels will then set their `SelectedData` properties whenever they complete loading (in the case that the MainViewModel finished first) or whenever `IsDirty` is set to true -- whichever comes first

Comment: I only have one ViewModel. It has 5 observable collections.

Comment: ok -- same principle applies. When the main entity completes loading there are two possibilities:
1. The other collections are still loading -- in which case you set a flag indicating the main data has loaded. Once the other collections load you set the remaining properties
2. The other collections finished loading -- in which case you set the remaining properties

Answer (score 0):

If they are quick loading you could just chain the loads calling the next load on the callback from the previous.

If not then leave all your collections at null/nothing (many people initialize them in the constructor) and in the load callback of each, Instantiate the collection before you fill it, leaving it empty if no entities/results are returned. Then call a function that checks that none of the collections are null/nothing, and calls the inotify for all of them at once.

A similar approach that would allow you to instantiate your collections before they are loaded, would be to create an attached property "isLoaded" for your collections and use that.